# Add/replace image in Keynote 9.1 (6369) from outside Photos or Movies

Tags: finder, photos, keynote

I am working in Keynote 9.1 (6369).

[Apple support](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/add-an-image-tan77aea6844/mac) shows one can drag-and-drop in an image. **But is there really no more direct way to, having clicked on the photo icon in the bottom-right corner of the media placeholder, navigate outside of the** `Photos` **or** `Movies` **directories?** That seems astounding.

Can I set the list of directories from which Keynote allows me to choose images? Or is there a setting to navigate via `Finder` instead of the default UI for choosing?

If this behavior is improved in the more recent versions of Keynote, that might be close to a reason to upgrade my OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add images via the "Insert > Choose…" menu item (bottom-most menu item in the Insert menu). This opens a regular Finder window.
You can also use the corresponding keyboard shortcut Shift-CMD-V.

[image: Keynote Insert Choose]

To replace an existing image, you select the image on the slide, choose the "Format > Image" sidebar and then click the "Replace" button (brings up Finder window again).

[image: Keynote Replace]

Answer (score 0):

In Keynote 9.2.1, if you can't find the image you're looking for in the built-in pop-up, you can simply drag and drop an image file from Finder into your slide.

I believe this feature is available in all versions of Keynote.